# how to start stop worklight server 6.2 on linux?

Tags: linux, ibm-mobilefirst, administration

I have Worklight Server and Appcenter installed on RHEL 6.4 and am unable to find commands to start & stop these servers gracefully. Primarily, I would like to do this to apply patches, make changes to databases etc.. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This would be better asked on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are referring to installed instances of Worklight Server and Application Center in a QA/UAT/Production environment.

This means that your Worklight Server and Application Center instances are deployed to some application server (either WAS, WAS Liberty or Tomcat). So the way to start and stop these instances would be via the commands available by the the used application server. You should probably then consult with the user documentation of the used application server for the commands. For example for Liberty: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_script.html

If you are in fact referring to the Worklight Development Server (Worklight Studio plug-in for Eclipse), there is no publically available way to stop the server from command line -- unless you are using the CLI tool to manage your development (working outside of Eclipse), [there you do have a command for it](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/05_11_Using_CLI_to_create_build_and_manage_Worklight_project_artifacts.pdf).